# React-router multiple routes (React components)

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router, server-side-swift, react-dom-server

Below are my routes.js that handles every request - this is for server side rendering in react - I have the following 2 files - I get hello world right now 
The main issue I have is - 
**Where do i handle other routes? I am confused here this part - how do I make base.js with static `<!Doctype><head><title></head>` - but with different components like /about & /other depending upon the request url?** please help me with this - this feels like a big road block for me - have been trying many examples but everything seems so complicated -

routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

router.get('*', function(request, response) {
    ReactRouter.match({
        routes: (
            <ReactRouter.Router history={ReactRouter.browserHistory}>
                <ReactRouter.Route path='/' component={require('./src/Components/layout/base')}>
                </ReactRouter.Route>
            </ReactRouter.Router>
        ),
        location: request.url
    }, function(error, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
        if (renderProps) {
            var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                <ReactRouter.RouterContext {...renderProps} />
            );
            response.send(html);
        } else {
            response.status(404).send('Not Found');
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

base.js

```
var React = require('react');
    module.exports = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello World!');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `{this.props.children}` within your base component. Here's an example:

```
import Header from './Header';
import React from 'react';

class Base extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Base;
```

Then you can create a sub-route within the base route you already have:

```
<ReactRouter.Route path='/' component={require('./src/Components/layout/base')}>

  <ReactRouter.Route path='/awesome-page' component={require('./src/Components/layout/awesome-page')}>
  </ReactRouter.Route>

</ReactRouter.Route>
```